# Fourier Transform of $|f|$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-transform

I take the definition of the Fourier transform of $f \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}^3)$ to be

$$ \widehat{f} (k) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^3} e^{-2 \pi i k \cdot x} f(x) dx $$

**Question:** Can we say anything useful about $\widehat{|f|}$ in terms of $\widehat{f}$?

Comment: The absolute value function is nonlinear. It doesn't play nice with Fourier transform.

Comment: Right. But are there any estimates? Maybe $L^p$-norm estimates?

Comment: Sure, Plancherel tells you that $\| \widehat{|f|} \|_{L^2} = \| f \|_{L^2}$, and Hausdorff-Young tells you $\| \widehat{|f|} \|_{L^{p'}} \leq c \| f \|_{L^p}$ for $1 < p < 2$, so we have some control on the $\widehat{|f|}$ in terms of $f$. But I am wondering if there is more.